# How to create an alphabet shape containing text with html css javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create several shapes which will look like different English alphabets and, each shape should contain text. I have an image file showing what I want to do. I want to do it only with html css javascript. I am not asking to teach me everything but references to different methods will be enough.

[image]

More Info: The content will be dynamically populated in the shapes.

Comment: well here is a good starter - simpsons only with css3 
http://pattle.github.io/simpsons-in-css/

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like, will the text inside the shapes be dynamically populated?

Comment: Yes, it will get feeds from twitter.

Answer (score 4):

[Closest you'll get without a ridiculous answer.](http://patorjk.com/software/taag)

This can generate many types of ASCII art. Go ahead. Go crazy.

I highly doubt someone will write out the entire story for you, but you can now use CSS shapes to define the line between an image and text.

Though, good luck with it.

[css-shapes](http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101)

Answer (score 3):

Tricky, but not impossible. You could use CSS shapes, but I'm not that sure on their browser compatibility. You could use an image, or type out each letter manually, but that's not very flexible.

You could map each letter out yourself, although it could take a while...but once you're done, you can completely customise their content and alter them very easily.

Here's the letter E!

http://jsfiddle.net/6XZkM/1/

```
var letter_e = [25,25,25,25,25,10,10,10,10,10,25,25,25,25,10,10,10,10,10,25,25,25,25,25];

var div = document.getElementById('content');
letter_e.forEach(function (count) {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'e';
    }
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '</br>';
});
```

Or personally, my favourite:

http://jsfiddle.net/6XZkM/2/

```
Writing out giant letters
with javascript is a bad
idea! Writing out giant
letters with javascript i
s a bad idea! Writing out
giant let
ters with
javascript
is a bad
idea! Writ
ing out giant letters wit
h javascript is a bad ide
a! Writing out giant lett
ers with javascript is a
bad idea!
Writing ou
t giant le
tters with
javascrip
t is a bad idea! Writing
out giant letters with ja
vascript is a bad idea! W
riting out giant letters
with javascript is a bad
```

**Edit:**

I got bored and so did a rudimentary version that can handle gaps in a letter. Here's the letter B!

http://jsfiddle.net/6XZkM/3/

Essentially with this version, when you map each letter, if you just specify a number, it'll print out that many letters on a line. If you specify an array, it'll alternate between spaces and letters.

So if you defined for example `[4,20,5,13,4]`, it would print out 4 letters, followed by 20 spaces, followed by 5 letters, followed by 13 spaces, followed by 4 letters, on a single line.

A major downside I can see with handling it like this is that you have to map out manually every single letter you want to use. It takes **alot** of time.

Comment: Wow! this seems interesting. I will try to implement it and report back... (Why is it a bad idea)

Comment: @PankilJoshi It's a bad idea because it takes alot of time and would require a fair amount of tweaking. It'll probably never look _exactly_ right, as some letters take up more space than others `W` vs `i`, so in some instances you could have weird looking shapes.

Answer (score -1):

```
gggggggggggggggggggg
gggggggggggggggggggg
ggggg           gggg
ggggg
ggggg
ggggg
ggggg       ggggggggg
ggggg       ggggggggg
ggggg           gggg
ggggg           gggg
gggggggggggggggggggg
gggggggggggggggggggg
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/kd43Y/